# Javascript: Cherrio is returning inconsistent results for anchor tag

Tags: javascript, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape websites and grab their `mailto` links:

```
const url = "https://www.cverification.com/";
axios.get(url).then(({ data }) => {
  const $_ = cheerio.load(data);
  const mailToLink = $_('a[href^="mailto:"]');
  console.log("maillllllllll: ", mailToLink);
  if (!mailToLink || !mailToLink.length) {
    console.log("NO EMAILLLL: ", url); // <------------ this prints
    return;
  }

  const email = mailToLink.attr("href").replace("mailto:", "");
  console.log("SUCCEEDEDDD", url, email);
});
```

However, Cheerio is returning a weird object for some of the links:

```
maillllllllll:  initialize {
  options:
   { withDomLvl1: true,
     normalizeWhitespace: false,
     xml: false,
     decodeEntities: true },
  _root:
   initialize {
     '0':
      { type: 'root',
        name: 'root',
        namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
        attribs: {},
```

This script works for some websites and not for others. When I visit https://www.cverification.com/ and run the code above line by line (just using jQuery) it works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: random hunch here but  I would double check that `data` being returned from your get request is a String before you load it into cheerio.

Comment: just checked and i can verify that it's the HTML. good try though

Comment: I checked the source code of https://www.cverification.com/ and we saw that it is using react. Since cheerio doesn't execute javascript code it can't find the anchors you're looking for

Comment: hm good catch. i just looked at the HTML too and it looks like it's just a div (probably cuz react inserts the components into the dom). that should explain it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As others in the comments have discovered, the site was using React and therefore the link was inserted after React injects all the components.

I fixed this by updating the user-agent of my request:

```
const instance = axios.create({
  headers: {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A4345d Safari/600.1.4"
  }
});
```

This fixed it!